# Updating state in one component in a set of recursive components, updates state for all

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display values in an array or object like a tree view in react and I am trying to render components recursively.

The rendering works as I wanted it to. However, I have arrows next to arrays and objects that you can click on to collapse or expand them. When I click on those arrows only that particular field should collapse. But, all its parents also get collapsed.

I have a state variable for this component which is being nested and clicking on the arrow updates the state to collapse it. However, all parent and child components in the recursion tree get updated.

Here is a sandbox version of what is happening: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-burnell-8jofi

I would like it to collapse only for component on which the arrow is being click on. Unable to debug why this is happening. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently dealing with the exact same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?